# How to use aspx page in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have aspx page and I want to use these pages in MVC3 but how ?

I have done these steps but I couldn't debug it

1. Create a folder that has my aspx page which is in View
2. I call partial helper to debug it in my cshtml file:

   ```
   @Html.Partial("~/Views/Payment/3DPay.aspx")
   ```

So what can I do to use aspx page in MVC 3 ?

Comment: if u use Partials why u need .aspx? create the partial view .cshtml and render him

Comment: I need aspx because I'm trying integrate Credit Payment which is in aspx file

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298666/aspx-page-in-mvc3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298666/aspx-page-in-mvc3)

Comment: Allright  I have learned how to do it. But I have another question I will ask