# How to show webforms page .aspx in VIEW MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webforms, reporting-services

My project developed in MVC3 Razor Tech. My master page and content page are developed with Razor MVC3. I want to show a SSRS report builder on my project. I searched in blogs and come to know that we can't show the SSRS reports in MVC3 Razor. 
Since We can used `'webform'` in MVC3 we can show the report.

Problems: In my project both master and content page are all developed with Razor `.cshtml` Since accessing `.aspx` is difficult.Correct me if I'm wrong.

Requirement: Please help me to show the webforms in the `'VIEW'` MVC3 Razor framwork.i.e My project landing page is the `webform`. In that webform page I need to show the SSRS report

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had to do it and so I worked for me :

Suppose you have a controller called **Summary** .
For this implementation, You don't need to add or modify any of the actions that you have.

Then, as you told me,  you add a file named "SkillReport.aspx" in your views folder

```
 Views/Summary/SkillReport.aspx
```

( initially left in blank SkillReport.aspx or just add some text like "Skill report" )

In Global.asax :

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

       routes.MapPageRoute("Report", "Report/{rptController}/{rptName}", "~/Views/{rptController}/{rptName}.aspx");
       ...
    }
```

> > ****--> I have attached the snapshot of my solution explorer
> >     [image]
> >     My routes.Mappageroute code is 
> >          "*routes.MapPageRoute("Report", "Report/Summary", "~/Views/Summary/SkillReport.aspx");*"
> >     Please change the mapPageRoute for the above folder structure.** <--

The values ​​enclosed in **{}** are **placeholders**. You must not give the name of the controller or report there. When a request is received, this route determines which controller to invoke by adding the suffix  "rptController" to the controller value in the URL to determine the type name of the controller that will handle the request. The *rptName* value in the URL determines which *WebForm.aspx* to call.

Suppose you need other two reports.

1. In **Summary** controller, and report name *FullNames*
2. In a controller named **Product**, and report name *List*.

Using the parameters you avoid having to create a route for each report.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Report", "Report/{rptController}/{rptName}", "~/Views/{rptController}/{rptName}.aspx");


http://localhost/Report/Summary/SkillReport  --> /Views/Summary/SkillReport.aspx
http://localhost/Report/Summary/FullNames    --> /Views/Summary/FullNames.aspx
http://localhost/Report/Product/List         --> /Views/Product/List.aspx
```

On this route we added:

1. "Report" is the name of this route, you can put any other
2. "Report/**{rptController}**/*{rptName}*" : This is the pattern URL to identify
       when to invoke your Report-WebForm, "Report" works as "key" and
       **{rptController}** is the name of the controller. rptController  will be assigned with the Controller name. In this case **Summary** and *rptName* with *SkillReport*
3. "~/Views/**{rptController}**/*{rptName}*.aspx" is the physical
       path. When using this route with **Summary** controller, and call *SkillReport* this will
       invoke to Views/**Summary**/*SkillReport*.aspx

Routing documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx#url_patterns

At this point you can verify that you can access your SkillReport.aspx in your development environment using :

```
http://localhost/Report/Summary/SkillReport
```

Or maybe at some particular port... like

```
http://localhost:1057/Report/Summary/SkillReport
```

Finally, SkillReport.aspx  (like this... check ProcessingMode...)

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SkillReport.aspx.cs" Inherits="XXX.SkillReport" %>

    <%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
        Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>



    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" >

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=100"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="frmRpt" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rpt" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="90%" AsyncRendering="false" ProcessingMode="Local" ShowRefreshButton="false">
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

With this tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" >
```

you achieve that show in Safari and other browsers.

To access the report from a VIEW (.cshtml) need to add a link. i. e. :

```
<a href="/Report/Summary/SkillReport" >Show My Report :) </a>
```

As a last comment, I recommend that after creating SkillReport.aspx enter in "**Design Mode**" and **drag from the toolbox the Reporting's controls**. This will automatically register the required values ​​in **web.config**

Comment: I hope it will be helpful. Feel free to add any other questions/changes.

Comment: @Mate.. Thanks.. I updated other question in ur solution in the format '-->Question<--'

Comment: @Mate.. I updated my question with snapshot. Please review and post the answer. Thanks

Comment: What should I add in controller? Since I'm getting this error- "The view at '~/Views/Report/ReportView.aspx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TModel>."

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597460/the-view-must-derive-from-webviewpage and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467808/getting-the-error-the-view-at-views-page-home-aspx-must-derive-from-viewpag

Answer (score 3):

Answer #1 was useful:

Just make sure that your order of MapRoutes is in the right order of precedence:

e.g.:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

           routes.MapPageRoute(
           routeName: "Report/", 
           routeUrl: "Report/{rptController}/{rptName}", 
           physicalFile: "~/Views/{rptController}/{rptName}.aspx"
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this would not be a recommended practice it is doable. I'm copying a link that shows you how to use two View Engines in the same project.

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/07/29/asp-net-mvc-3-using-multiple-view-engines-in-same-project.aspx

Let me know if this works for you.

**Update:**
This might be of help as well, another option looks like registering a route for your aspx page.

*[StackOverflow Post]* [Aspx page in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298666/aspx-page-in-mvc3)