# The view must derive from WebViewPage

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I had a working MVC application when I decided that it was time for some maintenance. 
My views were all under SHARED directory and I decided to move them into separate directories.

I implemented a CustomViewEngine that I found here:
[Can I specify a custom location to "search for views" in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964/can-i-specify-a-custom-location-to-search-for-views-in-asp-net-mvc/909594#909594)

View structure looks something like this

```
Views
    AppViews
    OtherAppViews
    ...
    Shared
    ...
```

This is an error that I am getting:

`The view at '~/Views/AppViews/SomeView.cshtml' must derive from ViewPage,`     `ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TModel>.`

I tried to inherit from `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` (as explained here: [The view must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage<TModel>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127462/the-view-must-derive-from-webviewpage-or-webviewpagetmodel)) , but when I do this I get an error saying that I can't use `@inherits` and `@model` at the same time.

Comment: Both your `web.config` are included in the project right? (One under Views the other under Root)

Comment: Yes, they are. I have not touched them.

Comment: There is another SO question that might help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127462/the-view-must-derive-from-webviewpage-or-webviewpagetmodel

Comment: @QuetiM.Porta if you read the question all the way to the end you will see that I referenced that question. Thanks

Comment: @gumenimeda Usually when I have this problem it has to do with my config file. I've never had this error other than that.. good luck

Comment: @Nate You may be right. Maybe it is not properly reading Web.config file. Will look into this. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Your CustomEngine should derive from `RazorViewEngine` instead of `WebFormViewEngine` since you use .cshtml files (Razor engine).

Docs:

- [RazorViewEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.razorviewengine%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)
- [WebFormViewEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webformviewengine%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)