# Asp.Net MVC 5 call WebForm.aspx under ROOT directory from a razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a webForm (WebForm1.aspx) added inside the root

[image: I have a webForm (WebForm1.aspx) added inside the root]

I want to call this WebForm1.aspx from a razor view when a div is clicked (div is placed inside the view with some styles) to a new browser tab.

Suppose **Controller** is X and **View** is Index

Below is some piece of index razor view code

```
<div class="column" 
style="flex:50%;padding:10px;" 
onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("WebForm1.aspx") + "'");">

</div>
```

NB : WebForm1.aspx has some RDL reportViewer.
When i call this WebForm1 using a partial view, the report is not rendering, when i call directly WebForm1.aspx by entering URL on broswer it shows report. Some postback issues happening i guess!
Help me guys, How to call this form inside a view directly ?

Comment: if you use `window.location.href` it's going to open the link in the current page better use:`window.open('" + @Url.Action("WebForm1.aspx") + "', '_blank');` instead. here `_blank` represents a new window/tab. And if you don't have a particular need try using an anchor(`a`) tag with target as `_blank`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show webforms page .aspx in VIEW MVC3 Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171404/how-to-show-webforms-page-aspx-in-view-mvc3-razor)